# How can I see the track of a flight from a year ago?

Tags: online-tracking

I want to get tracking data from a particular GA flight that took place over a year ago. I know the departure airport and the city the plane landed near, and I can narrow it down to a few possible arrival airports. I know the day the flight landed, and it took off either early that morning or late the previous night. I also know the airplane's registration number.

How can I get more information about this flight?

Comment: Have you tried Flightaware or other such apps?

Comment: I don’t know about ADSBexchange, but the main commercial sites/apps (FlightWare and FlightRadar24) only provide a few days of history for free.  Then you pay for increasingly expensive subscriptions in order to get longer histories.  But I believe they both max out at one year.